# Calculate derivative at the mean unless optional arguments are present?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function `y=f(x1, x2, v1)` where `x1` and `x2` are continuous variables and `v1` is `0` or `1`. For example:

```
myfunc <- function(x1, x2, v1){
  e <- exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1)
  return(e)
}
```

I would like to create a function `h` that takes as arguments a data frame, a function, and has as optional arguments values for the variables of the function. This function `h` should return a vector with `dy/dx`. If no optional arguments are present, `dy/dx` is evaluated at the mean of the parameters. But, optionally I would like to be able to pass a value for that can be used instead of the mean. For example, `v1=0`. Is this possible?

This is what I have right now:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100, 2, 1), x2= rnorm(100, 4, 1),
                 v1=sample(x = c(0,1), size = 100, replace = T))
numDeriv::grad(myfunc, x=mean(df$x1), x2=mean(df$x2), v1=0)
```

Alas, I cannot think of a way to write the function that takes the optional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On entry:

- `FUN` is a user input function;
- `dx` is a length-1 character vector, giving the variable name the (partial) derivatives is with respect to (w.r.t);
- `dat` is a data frame, giving all values where we want to evaluate derivatives;
- `opt` by default is `NULL`; but if given, must be a list.

On exit, it returns a vector, giving partial derivatives w.r.t `"x1"`, evaluated at `df[[x1]]`, with others variables fixed, either at column mean of `df`, or values provided in `opt`.

Example call, using OP's original example, is:

```
h(myfunc, "x1", df)
h(myfunc, "x1", df, list(v1 = 1))
h(myfunc, "x1", df, list(x2 = 2, v1 = 0))
h(myfunc, "x2", df, list(x1 = 1.2))
```

This function is:

```
h <- function(FUN, dx, dat, opt = NULL) {
  ## check arguments of h
  if (missing(FUN)) stop("No given function: FUN")
  if (!is.function(FUN)) stop("arguments 'FUN' is not a function!")
  if (missing(dx)) stop("No given variable to evaluate partial derivatives: dx")
  if (!is.character(dx)) stop("arguments 'dx' must be a character!")
  if (length(dx) > 1) stop("arguments 'dx' must be of length 1")
  if (missing(dat)) stop("No data provided: dat")
  if (!is.data.frame(dat)) stop("arguments 'dat' must be a data frame!")
  OPT <- !is.null(opt); if (OPT && !is.list(opt)) stop("optional arguments must be provided as a list!")
  ## get arguments of FUN
  FUN_args <- formalArgs(FUN)
  ## get column vars of dat
  dat_vars <- colnames(dat)
  ## get names of optional arguments
  if (OPT) opt_vars <- names(opt)
  ## need to ensure dx is both inside dat and a function argument of FUN
  if (!dx %in% FUN_args) stop(paste("unknown function argumens of FUN:", dx))
  if (!dx %in% dat_vars) stop(paste("variable", dx, "is not in `dat`!"))
  ## now, let's take care of other arguments of FUN, if there are any
  n <- length(FUN_args <- FUN_args[-match(dx, FUN_args)])
  if (n > 0) {
    ## are there optional arguments?
    if (OPT) {
      ## extract optional arguments that are in FUN_args (refining opt)
      opt_vars <- FUN_args[FUN_args %in% opt_vars]
      opt <- opt[opt_vars]
      ## excluce opt_vars from dat_vars
      FUN_args <- FUN_args[-match(opt_vars, FUN_args)]
      }
    ## now, all remaining FUN_args must be found inside dat_vars
    missing_vars <- FUN_args[!FUN_args %in% dat_vars]
    if (length(missing_vars)) stop(paste("Those variables are not found from `dat` or `opt`:", missing_vars))
    ## now, there are no missing vars, so we compute column mean from dat for FUN_args
    tmp <- lapply(dat[FUN_args], FUN = mean)
    ## combine tmp and opt
    opt <- c(opt, tmp)
    }
  ## prepare function call!
  text <- "numDeriv::grad(FUN, x = dat[[dx]]"
  FUN_args <- names(opt)
  for (i in 1:length(opt)) {
    expr <- paste0("opt[['", FUN_args[i], "']]")
    expr <- paste(FUN_args[i], expr, sep = " = ")
    text <- paste(text, expr, sep = ", ")
    }
  expr <- paste0(text,")")
  ## evaluate partial derivatives
  eval(parse(text = expr))
  }
```

---

Note, this function does various check, but does not check everything at the moment. For example, you may want to further ensure:

- `opt[[i]]` is a length-1 numeric vector, for any `i in 1:length(opt)`;
- appropriate handling with `NA`.

The `eval`, `parse` way of constructing the final function call to `numDeriv::grad` may not be the optimal way, but unfortunately I can not think up a better way at the moment. Sometimes I see `match.call()`, `do.call()` when reading source code of some R packages, but not entirely sure what they are doing. Possibly they are better alternatives? but at least this function works, which is, to be honest, better than nothing, after 4-5 hours' work.

---

**Update: regarding your comment**

I will explain with data, what `h` is doing. You example data frame is something like:

```
             x1       x2 v1
1    1.79741154 6.484015  0
2    1.59461279 3.655893  1
3    1.59738477 4.053226  1
4    3.41523605 4.079614  0
5    3.84462359 2.871799  1
.             .        .  .
.             .        .  .
```

with column means:

```
      x1       x2       v1 
1.921273 4.026466 0.500000
```

Now,

- for function call `h(myfunc, "x1", df)` with no optional arguments in `opt` list, it returns partial derivatives at the following points:

  ```
               x1       x2        v1
  1    1.79741154 4.026466  0.500000
  2    1.59461279 4.026466  0.500000
  3    1.59738477 4.026466  0.500000
  4    3.41523605 4.026466  0.500000
  5    3.84462359 4.026466  0.500000
  .             .        .         .
  .             .        .         .
  ```

  which takes all values of `df[["x1"]]`, but replicate column means `mean(df[["x2"]])` and `mean(df[[v1]])`.
- for function call `h(myfunc, "x1", df, opt = list(v1 = 1))`, it returns partial derivatives at the following points:

  ```
               x1       x2 v1
  1    1.79741154 4.026466  1
  2    1.59461279 4.026466  1
  3    1.59738477 4.026466  1
  4    3.41523605 4.026466  1
  5    3.84462359 4.026466  1
  .             .        .  .
  .             .        .  .
  ```

  which takes all values of `df[["x1"]]`, but replicate column means `mean(df[["x2"]])` and provided value `v1 = 1`.
- for function call `h(myfunc, "x1", df, opt = list(x2 = 2, v1 = 1))`, it returns partial derivatives at the following points:

  ```
               x1 x2 v1
  1    1.79741154  2  1
  2    1.59461279  2  1
  3    1.59738477  2  1
  4    3.41523605  2  1
  5    3.84462359  2  1
  .             .  .  .
  .             .  .  .
  ```

  which takes all values of `df[["x1"]]`, but replicate optional values `x2 = 2` and `v1 = 1`.
- for function call `h(myfunc, "x2", df, list(x1 = 1.2))`, it returns partial derivatives at the following points:

  ```
        x1       x2   v1
  1    1.2 6.484015  0.5
  2    1.2 3.655893  0.5
  3    1.2 4.053226  0.5
  4    1.2 4.079614  0.5
  5    1.2 2.871799  0.5
  .      .        .    .
  .      .        .    .
  ```

  which takes all values of `df[["x2"]]`, but replicate column mean `mean(df[["v1"]]) = 0.5` and optional value `x1 = 1.2`.
- for function call `h(myfunc, "x1", df, opt = list(x1 = 1))` will have the same effect as `h(myfunc, "x1", df)`, i.e., `h` will ignore `x1 = 1` because you pass `"x1"` to `dx`.

**The function always return a vector, because I put:**

```
  ## prepare function call!
  text <- "numDeriv::grad(FUN, x = dat[[dx]]"
```

instead of

```
  ## prepare function call!
  text <- "numDeriv::grad(FUN, x = mean(dat[[dx]])"
```

**I do this because I don't know why you pass in a data frame `df`, if you only want to return a single value.**

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your work! That said, I'm confused. `d myfunc / d x1` should be a number not a vector. The analytical solution is `d myfunc / d x1 = 0.1*exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1)`. I think the problem is that the function is being evaluated at every point in `df[[x1]]` instead of the mean of the specified value. Ideally, the outcome should be a vector but (on this example) size 3 where the elements are `dy/dx1, dy/dx2, dy/dv1`. Sorry about the lack of clarity in my question.

Comment: Yes, I want the gradient. The only reason I wanted to have a data frame as an argument is that if you don't pass values to the function it calculates the gradient at the mean of each variable. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, i created a follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301838/calculate-gradient-at-the-mean-unless-optional-arguments-are-present