# Calculate gradient at the mean unless optional arguments are present?

Tags: r

In an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266143/calculate-derivative-at-the-mean-unless-optional-arguments-are-present/37266326?noredirect=1#comment62124841_37266326) @Zheyuan Li show me how to create a function that returns the derivative of a function at the mean unless other optimal arguments are present.

I would like to modify that function to return the gradient. For example, if i pass this function:

```
myfunc <- function(x1, x2, v1){
  e <- exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1)
  return(e)
}
```

I would like to get back

```
gradient <- c(0.1 * exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1),
              0.2 * exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1),
              exp(0.1*x1+0.2*x2+v1))
```

evaluated at `x1 == mean(data$x1)`, `x2==mean(data$x2)`, `v1==mean(data$v1)`
and unless I pass a value for any of those variables.

I think an additional complication is that `v1` is a binary variable, so the the function should return the difference of the function evaluated at 0 and 1 instead of trying to take the derivative. `v1` is an indicator variable, something like an indicator for female. So it makes no sense to take a derivative for v1 or evaluate at the mean. Instead the default should be `v1==0` unless a value is provided.

Comment: The function is continuous. But in my data, the variable `v1` can only take the values `0` or `1`. Think of `v1` as something like an indicator for `female`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom is a version which works for all continuous variables. It can work for generic differentiable functions involving only continuous variables. This function is quite interesting and useful, and I might keep if for my own use as well. Except the function you give, we can try other (slightly more complicated) examples like:

```
f1 <- function (x1, x2, x3, x4) x4 * sin(x1) + 2 * x1 * cos(x2) + log(x3) + sqrt(x4)
h(f1, opt = list(x1 = 1.32, x2 = 2.87, x3 = 9.14, x4 = 1.01))
```

and it returns:

```
> h(f1, opt = list(x1 = 1.32, x2 = 2.87, x3 = 9.14, x4 = 1.01))
$loc
  x1   x2   x3   x4 
1.32 2.87 9.14 1.01 

$grad
        x1         x2         x3         x4 
-1.6760325 -0.7082224  0.1094092  1.4662337
```

On entry, either `dat` or `opt` can be missing, and they default to `NULL`; however, they can't be both missing, and the function will check this. On exit, it gives a list, containing location `$loc` where gradient is evaluated, as well as gradient value `$grad`.

Example call (using OP's example `df` and `myfunc` in previous post):

```
> h(myfunc, df)
$loc
      x1       x2       v1 
1.971663 4.043786 0.540000 

$grad
       x1        x2        v1 
0.4692303 0.9384607 4.6923033

> h(myfunc, df, opt = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, v1 = 0))
$loc
x1 x2 v1 
 1  2  0 

 $grad
        x1        x2        v1 
 0.1648721 0.3297443 1.6487213

> h(myfunc, df, opt = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2))
$loc
      x1   x2   v1 
    1.00 2.00 0.54 

$grad
       x1        x2        v1 
0.2829217 0.5658434 2.8292170
```

**The function is also written in a robust way**. For example, passing irrelevant variable does not matter:

```
> h(myfunc, df, opt = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, y = 0.4))
$loc
  x1   x2   v1 
1.00 2.00 0.54 

$grad
       x1        x2        v1 
0.2829217 0.5658434 2.8292170
```

When variables are incomplete, it will complain:

```
> df <- df[-2]   ## drop "x2"
> h(myfunc, df, opt = list(x1 = 0))   ## "x2" also not in opt list
Error in h(myfunc, df, opt = list(x1 = 0)) (from h) : 
  Those variables are not found from `dat` or `opt`: x2
```

The order of the variables in `df` or `opt` does not need to be the same as in `FUN`. During execution of the function, it will reorder variables accordingly to be consistent with the variable order in `FUN`.

---

```
h <- function(FUN, dat = NULL, opt = NULL) {
  ## check arguments of h
  if (missing(FUN)) stop("No given function: FUN")
  if (!is.function(FUN)) stop("arguments 'FUN' is not a function!")
  DAT <- !missing(dat)
  if (DAT && !is.data.frame(dat)) stop("arguments 'dat' must be a data frame!")
  OPT <- !is.null(opt); if (OPT && !is.list(opt)) stop("optional arguments must be provided as a list!")
  if (!DAT && !OPT) stop("Neither 'dat' nor 'opt' is provided!")
  ## check variables
  FUN_args <- formalArgs(FUN)  ## get arguments of FUN
  dat_vars <- colnames(dat)  ## get column vars of dat
  dat_vars <- dat_vars[dat_vars %in% FUN_args]
  dat <- dat[dat_vars]
  opt_vars <- names(opt)  ## get names of optional arguments
  if (OPT) {
    opt_vars <- opt_vars[opt_vars %in% FUN_args]
    opt <- opt[opt_vars]
    }
  ## checking whether variables are complete
  missing_vars <- FUN_args[!FUN_args %in% c(dat_vars, opt_vars)]
  if (length(missing_vars)) stop(paste("Those variables are not found from `dat` or `opt`:", paste(missing_vars, collapse = ", ")))
  ## get column mean from "dat" for those vars not in opt_vars
  dat_vars <- dat_vars[!dat_vars %in% opt_vars]
  if (length(dat_vars)) {
    val <- lapply(dat[dat_vars], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    opt <- c(val, opt)  ## combine val and opt
    }
  ## convert them into "friendly" character vector
  opt <- unlist(opt[match(FUN_args, names(opt))])
  val <- paste(names(opt), opt, sep = " = ")
  ## now, let's iterate from all arguments of FUN, taking derivatives
  n <- length(FUN_args);
  gradient <- numeric(n); names(gradient) <- names(opt)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    ## prepare function call!
    init <- paste0("numDeriv::grad(FUN, x = ", opt[i])
    expr <- paste(val[-i], collapse = ", ")
    expr <- paste0(paste(init, expr, sep = ", "), ")")
    ## evaluate partial derivatives
    gradient[i] <- eval(parse(text = expr))
    }
  ## return
  list(loc = opt, grad = gradient)
  }
```